# Nodejs deleting uploaded files after specific time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building a hosting server with Node and MongoDB. Process of working look something like this:

1. User open page with form which contains 4 inputs:

   - sender email
   - receiver email
   - message from sender to receiver
   - files (multiple)
2. User fills all inputs properly and sends POST request on server.
3. Server handles form with multer and saves files, then in callback the object with fields data where is stored info received from form is prepared and sent to database on MongoLab.
4. In callback of saving doc in database, server sends mails to sender and receiver with generated link from where they can download uploaded files.

Now I would like to implement additional input to form, where user can set date when his files should be deleted from the server.

So there are two things to do: delete files and delete doc in database on time set by the user.

Do you have some ideas how to implement such thing?

Comment: [TTL Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) may be a solution for you. Failing that you probably should set up your own "cron" based process, possibly based on [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) or a similar implementation.

Comment: @NeilLunn Looks pretty interesting. I will try to implement it and give you feedback. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: @NeilLunn , thanks, this idea with node-cron was great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a file, you can simply use `fs.unlink()`

```
const fs = require('fs');

const deleteFile = (file) => {
       fs.unlink("path/to/file/folder/"+file, (err) => {
           if (err) throw err;
       }
}
```

You want to create a `setTimeout()`, but you need to find how much time is remaining before the date provided by the user, you should do something like this:

```
const time_remaining = (date_provided) => new Date(date_provided) - new Date();
```

Then just use `setTimeout()`:

```
let timeOuts = []; // We create an array of timeouts in case we want to cancel one later
// I assume you use express and body-parser
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
     const timer = setTimeout( () => deleteFile(req.body.file), time_remaining (req.body.date));
     timeOuts.push(timer);
}
```

Comment: Seems interesting! I am going to try it and will give you feedback later. Thanks for your time! :)